# How to preview a React Portal component using storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook, react-portal

I have this code:

**index.html**

```
...
<body>
  <div id="example-root"></div>
</body>
...
```

**Component.tsx**

```
...
const exampleRoot = document.getElementById("example-root")

function Component() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(<div>...</div>, exampleRoot)
}
```

**Stories.tsx**

```
...
const ExampleStory = () => (
  <>
    <div id="example-root"></div>
    <Component />
  </>  
)
```

I need to render `<Component/>` on storybook, but the problem is that `<Component/>` needs to find
the `#example-root` element to be rendered, but when I run the storybook it's unable to find this root element and it can't be rendered, but when I run the same code at normal page it works fine, except in storybook, so the problem is on storybook.

I think it's happening because the `<Component />` is mounted before the storybook, so the the component can't find the `#example-root` element. A funny thing is that after everything has been rendered(component & storybook) if I do any change at `<Component />` code and save it, then it works! The `<Component />` find the root and is rendered.

So, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer for this**

If you need to render a component that is a React Portal, go to **.storybook** folder in your workspace, and then create a new file called **preview-body.html**, inside this file you just need to create the portal root tag, for example:

```
// .storybook > preview-body.html

<div id="example-root"></div>
```

Now your React Portal component is ready to be rendered in your story.

Answer (score 0):

it could be render by adding  on Template, but it works only when the controls are changed.